# Is it known whether Kaori Miyazono is half-Japanese?

Tags: your-lie-in-april

Her dad had a pretty big nose, if we want to go there. Nothing is said on the Wikia. And this question doesn't really matter... but I'm sure people want to know! Was Miyazono half-Japanese? What indications are there that she was?

Comment: Apparently her father has a Japanese name. For all I care, he doesn't look overtly foreign either, so I'm assuming Kaori probably isn't, particularly since it seems like the sort of detail that would be disclosed _somewhere_.

Comment: We can't even be sure she is blonde, she might be dyeing.

Comment: @Mindwin your phrasing... that better be intentional.

Comment: @Mindwin: In the OVA, which shows the characters as children, Kaori already has blonde hair, but I don't think this is actually indicative of much. (Takeshi is also already blond as a kid, and Tsubaki already has her brown hair. I find it difficult to imagine small children dyeing their hair, and well, hair colour in anime these days doesn't seem too consistently realistic anyway.)

Comment: @Maroon so she wasn't dyeing. one less "e", then.

Comment: I don't even see why this question gets upvotes. This is as good as asking if character X is half japanese because his/her parent/s has Y feature. Completely speculative and unsubstantiated to even begin as a question.

Comment: This question is not primarily opinion-based; a factual answer exists and is one of "yes, she is"; "no, she isn't"; or "there is no evidence for or against her being half-Japanese". If you think the question is bad, please cast downvotes instead of voting to close it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no evidence to suggest that Kaori is half-Japanese. I discuss my reasons for this assertion below.

- The fan wiki for *Your Lie in April* makes no such assertions about the ethnicity of Kaori. Were there an indication or (obvious) suggestion that Kaori is half-Japanese in official material, I would expect someone to have noted it.
- Kaori's parentage is straightforward, and her parents have Japanese names and do not look overtly foreign.
- We cannot extrapolate any information about ethnicity from the characters' hair colours. While Kaori had blonde hair even as a child (as seen in the OVA), so did Takeshi. Tsubaki already had brown hair (rather than black) as a child. Takeshi's sister, Nagi, is also blonde. It is difficult to imagine primary school students dyeing their hair, but it is also difficult to imagine that *all* of these characters have significant non-Japanese heritage. It is best to chalk this up to a lack of realism in anime hair colours.

As far as I am concerned, I would thus err (at the time of writing) on the side of assuming that Kaori is not half-Japanese. Were Kaori half-Japanese, it would seem to be such a large character detail that it would have to be disclosed *somewhere*.

Comment: Two other possible pieces of evidence stem from (1) Kaori's grandparents (which are mentioned in the wiki, but whom I don't recall seeing) and (2) the live-action film, which I have not watched (although it's not uncommon for films to misrepresent "canon" ethnicity).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct answer to this question, but the fact that she has blue eyes is what would leave me to believe she could be at least only half Japanese. This trait is almost never found in people of Asian decent specifically Japanese. Often times I have also noticed that in many other Animes they make the foreigners (western/European) also have blonde hair and blue eyes. (oc she could be dying her hair.)