# Is Menma from Anohana half-Japanese half-Russian?

Tags: anohana

I saw a comment [under a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDVFcYCTeWQ&t) which says the following:

> A: I’m not sure but wasn’t menma half japanese half russian?
>
> > [...]
> >
> > B: yes. the father is japanese and the *mother is russian.*
> >
> > [...]
> >
> > C: well, that's explain why she's the only one with unique hair in the anime
> >
> > [...]
> >
> > D: I’ve noticed in anime if you russian you have gray-ish hair. For example Viktor (Yuri on ice), Lev and Elisa (Haikyuu) and Menma

This is somewhat correct as [Irene Honma](https://anohana.fandom.com/wiki/Ir%C3%A8ne_Honma) (mother of Menma) is non-Japanese. But is she actually Russian? There is no mention of Irene being Russian in wiki apart from a note that says:

> The name Irène means "peace" in *Greek*.

**Question**: Is there any information in source material(manga) regarding the actual ethnicity of Irene Honma? If so, is she Russian?

---

Related discussion: [Is it known whether Kaori Miyazono is half-Japanese?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/38293/is-it-known-whether-kaori-miyazono-is-half-japanese)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Menma is quarter-Russian.

Here is the quote from [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%82%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A5%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%9F%E8%8A%B1%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E3%82%92%E5%83%95%E9%81%94%E3%81%AF%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A0%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%80%82)

> 本間 芽衣子（ほんま めいこ）/ めんま
> .. **ロシア人**[24]の血を引く母イレーヌから受け継いだ銀髪碧眼と白い肌から、儚げな印象を与える**クォーター**[25]の少女。

ロシア人＝Russian, クォーター=quarter.

The sources are:

> [24] 『オトナアニメ』vol.21、洋泉社〈洋泉社MOOK〉、2011年8月8日、46-77頁。ISBN 978-4-86248-772-8。p50

and

> [25] 小説版(novelized version)
>
> 『あの日見た花の名前を僕達はまだ知らない。(上)』、2011年7月25日発売[1](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%82%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A5%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%9F%E8%8A%B1%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E3%82%92%E5%83%95%E9%81%94%E3%81%AF%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A0%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%80%82)、ISBN 978-4-8401-3957-1
>
> 『あの日見た花の名前を僕達はまだ知らない。(下)』、2012年8月10日発売[2]、ISBN 978-4-8401-4689-0